# Correct use of T-Test?

Tags: t-test, crossover-study

I'm new to Cross Validated and have read some posts but I'd like to ask if I have set up this study and chosen the correct significance test.

**A quick rundown:**

- Four week study
- Same 11 Students all four weeks
- Two weeks in condition 0

  - 90 incidents
- Two weeks in condition 1

  - 18 incidents
- Measurements are in minutes of 'episodes'
- Episodes are not paired

**The Plan:**

Use Excel to run a two tailed non-paired t-test assuming equal variances to see if there is a difference in the means.

**Concerns & Questions:**

1. Condition 1 ended up severely right skewed violating the ideal normal distribution rule.
2. Many more data points for Condition 0 than for Condition 1
3. Is this the proper use of non-paired, non-equal variance assumptions?
4. Is there a better test to use?

I tried a log10 function to force the distribution to 'normal' and received a similar result.  My Interpretation is that Condition 1 lengthened the mean time but I'm hesitant to conclude this because of the concerns listed above.

Any thoughts?  Thank You!

**Results:**
[image]

Comment: Since the number of incidents (90 vs. 18) is also random (if I understand the question correctly), comparing the means is not the right thing to do for comparing the conditions. It makes more sense to compare the total time of all incidents.

Comment: @ZahavaKor I don't see it says anywhere it's random?

Comment: It's clear to me from the description - "episodes" are usually random occurrences. Maybe the OP can clarify this.

Comment: The episodes are outbursts by the students with a predefined set of behaviors.  Each episode would be independent of next (well, usually anyways.  I haven't looked to see if they are clustered in time, eg the kid is having a bad day and he has 5 episodes in single day)

Comment: Also, even in the second phase (second 2 weeks) it was possible for COndition 0 to exist so I couldn't just add up the time for each condition.

Comment: The data you need to collect is: For condition 0 add all lengths of episodes for each student and get x_1,...,x_11. Then add for condition 1 all lengths of episodes for each student and get y_1,...,y_11. Now do a paired t-test on these two sets of numbers. The test must be paired because it's the same students. Given the numbers you supplied the result will probably be significant.

Comment: is x_1 the mean or the total minutes for the student in condition 0?